# Implicit exception specification differs for inline and out-of-line definition?

Tags: c++, implicit-declaration

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) = default;
    X(X&&) = default;
    X& operator = (const X&) = default;
    X& operator = (X&&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<X>);

    return 0;
}
```

The move assignment operator appears to be implicitly `noexcept`, since the static assertion passes.

However, *defining* it out-of-line makes the assertion fail:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) = default;
    X(X&&) = default;
    X& operator = (const X&) = default;
    X& operator = (X&&); //= default;
};

X& X::operator=(X&&) = default;

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<X>);

    return 0;
}
```

Why do they behave differently?

Comment: `X& operator = (X&&);` is not `noexcept`. The fact you later use `=default` to simplify implementation does not matter. Definition cannot change declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your second code snippet, the move-assignment function is actually *user-provided*, because you have (explicitly) declared it – but not defaulted it – ***in its first declaration***.

From [this Draft C++17 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) (bold emphasis mine):

> ##### 11.4.2 Explicitly-defaulted functions        [dcl.fct.def.default]
>
> …
>  
>  <sup>5</sup>    … A
> function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not explicitly
> defaulted or deleted ***on its first declaration***. A user-provided
> explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly defaulted after its
> first declaration) is defined at the point where it is explicitly
> defaulted; if such a function is implicitly defined as deleted, the
> program is ill-formed.

To get the same behaviour (i.e., to make that 'defaulted' function `noexcept`) as in the first snippet, but without specifying the `= default` in the **declaration**, you will need to explicitly add the `noexcept` attribute, both to the declaration and to the later definition:

```cpp
struct X
{
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) = default;
    X(X&&) = default;
    X& operator = (const X&) = default;
    X& operator = (X&&) noexcept; // Add "noxcept" here ...
};


X& X::operator=(X&&) noexcept = default; // ... AND here!

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<X>);

    return 0;
}
```